# Error deleting project in TFS

Tags: tfs

I created a "Test" project that I want to delete, using the following command:
TfsDeleteProject /server:xyz\sqlserver2008 “Test“
Getting this error:
TF30076: The server name or Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) you typed, 
xyz\sqlserver2008, cannot be
resolved to a Team Foundation server.
If you type a server name, it must match the name you typed in the
Add Team Foundation Server dialog.  If you type a URI, it must use
the following syntax: http[s]://:
The server instance is valid. (The installation of TFS is app tier and db are on seperate boxes) What might be going on ?

xyz is eht server name, sqlserver2008 is the db instance. For eg. I access the db using sql server management studio client app using xyz\sqlserver2008 as dbname.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory: `If you type a server name, it must match the name you typed in the Add Team Foundation Server dialog`

Comment: What is `xyz\` in your server name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the full server URI including the http:// and :port. Also look for these error numbers in the MSDN.

Edit: Follow the first link, Andrew posted that's where I got my info from :)

Comment: Beat me to it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337633%28VS.80%29.aspx

Also, 

To correct this error, "Specify the full server URI. The full server URI is http://server:port. For example the AdventureWorks server URI is http://AdventureWorks:8080. To correct this error, Connect to Team Foundation Server through Team Explorer. This will store information about the server on the client computer. For more information, see How to: Connect to Team Foundation Server." Basically it needs the full URL and try rebuilding/refreshing your project. Might not even be there anymore...